# vba specific text copy to another tab

Tags: excel, vba

Having issues with some vba, if anyone can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated, currently my code is returning a full row of data and it is returning multiple rows, this is my current code.

```
    Sub BUTTONtest_Click()
Dim c As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Two Years")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Two Years League")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("G6:K6")   ' Do 50 rows
    If c.Text = "OVER" Then
       Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

I need to look at each row and in each row if the word "OVER" appears I need it to return the information in the side bar e.g. column B I would need this to apply for each wee section e.g. Column C- F should return the number from column B and H-K should return G etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This?

```
Sub BUTTONtest_Click()
Dim c As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Two Years")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Two Years League")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet

For i = 1 To 3 'Number of ¿wees?
    For Each c In Source.Range(Cells(6, 5 * i - 2), Cells(50, 5 * i + 1)) ' Do 50 rows
        If c.Text = "OVER" Then
            Target.Cells(j, 1) = Source.Cells(c.Row, 5 * i - 3)
           j = j + 1
        End If
    Next c
Next i

End Sub
```

**EDIT**
If don't want repeated rows, try this one:

```
Sub BUTTONtest_Click()
Dim c As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Two Years")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Two Years League")

j = 3     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
a = 1
For i = 1 To 3 'Number of ¿wees?
    For Each c In Source.Range(Cells(6, 5 * i - 2), Cells(50, 5 * i + 1)) ' Do 50 rows
        If c.Text = "OVER" Then
            If a <> c.Row Then
                Target.Cells(j, 1) = Source.Cells(c.Row, 5 * i - 3)
                j = j + 1
                a = c.Row
            End If
        End If
    Next c
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for this it does what I need It to do could you possibly explain what this part does `For Each c In Source.Range(Cells(6, 5 * i - 2), Cells(50, 5 * i + 1))` and `Target.Cells(j, 1) = Source.Cells(c.Row, 5 * i - 3)` or would you know of any sites that would explain this better for me?

Comment: You define a range as `Range(TopLeftCell, BottomRightCell)`. And a cell as `Cells(Row,Column)`. Combine the two and it is `Range(Cells(row1,column1),Cells(row2, column2))`. But in your case, there are three wees (`i = 1 to 3`), each range starting in columns `5 * i - 2` and ending in columns `5 * i + 1`. Please mark as accepted if it suits your needs....

Comment: More details, just in case: wee 1 starts in column 3, wee 2 starts in column 8, wee 3 starts in column 13. In excel, insert an XY plot of values (1,3),(2,8),(3,13) --> linear regression, --> show equation.

Comment: thankyou I'm trying to wrap my head around it at the moment... if I wanted to also put in the information from row 5 at a later date would this be easily included?

Comment: Just add `Target.Cells(j, 2) = Source.Cells(5, c.Column)` (if I correctly understand what you are asking for).

Comment: Keep in mind that, when there are several "OVER" in a row, only one of them is written into Target sheet (if you use the second piece of code).

Comment: If you don't mind my saying, close the excel file, and with paper and a pencil get clear WHAT you want. Then open the file, and think HOW to do it: "First solve the problem, then write the code".

Comment: thanks for the explanation its been really helpful an yea writing it out is what I'm trying to do I'm just trying to pre-empt what I could be asked for... I get told one thing and then they just want another thing added and another and another so I'm trying to work out where to draw the line

Comment: In that case, I can add another quote: "Walking on water and developing software from a specification are easy if both are frozen." :)

Answer (score 1):

you could try this code (commented)

```
Option Explicit

Sub BUTTONtest_Click()
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet
    Dim iSection As Long
    Dim sectionIniCol As Long, sectionEndCol As Long

    ' Change worksheet designations as needed
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Two Years")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Two Years League")

    With Source '<--| reference 'Source' sheet
        With .Range("B6:F" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row) '<--| reference its columns "B:F" range from row 6 down to last non empty cell in column "B"
            With .Offset(, -1).Resize(, 1) '<--| reference corresponding cells in column "A" (which is an empty column)
                For iSection = 1 To 3 '<-- loop over all your three 5-columns sections
                    sectionIniCol = (iSection - 1) * 5 + 2 '<-- evaluate current section initial col
                    sectionEndCol = sectionIniCol + 4 '<-- evaluate current section ending col
                    .FormulaR1C1 = "=if(countif(RC" & sectionIniCol + 1 & ":RC" & sectionEndCol & ",""OVER"")>0,1,"""")" '<-- write (temporary) formulas in column "A" cells to result "1" should at least one "OVER" occurrence be in corresponding cells of current section columns
                    If WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Cells) > 1 Then Intersect(.Columns(sectionIniCol), .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers).EntireRow).Copy Target.Cells(Target.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) '<-- if any occurrence of "OVER" has been found then copy section initial column cells corresponding to column "A" cells marked with "1" and paste them in from first empty row of 'Target' sheet...
                Next iSection
                .ClearContents '<--| delete (temporary) formulas in target column "A"
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: should your data spread over such a tiny row range as the one you posted (50 rows) this approach will also prove fast enough. Should your data considerably grow in rows number (some thousands plus) then different approaches (filtering, arrays) would be more performant

Comment: @Paula: not a feedback whatsoever? That's what makes me think maybe helping people it's not that worth

Comment: apologies I haven't been on in a number of days I found that your code worked well however as I will only remain at a static 50 rows I felt that it was easier to go with the un-adjusting code. Also my very basic knowledge In vba meant that I didn't fully understand your code but I have been taking the time to try and get my head around it and how to make changes to it. I think it may come in useful for another piece of work entirely thank you for your help